# What Programming Language Would Be Best For Ubuntu Programming?

Tags: programming, c#

Hi I've recently switched from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 12.10 and love the OS. However I have had trouble deciding which programming Language would be the all-around best for Ubuntu programming. I have no problem learning a harder language, I already know a good amount of C++ and C#. I really like C# but I've heard it doesn't mix well with Ubuntu.

What would be the best-integrated languages for Ubuntu, and good IDEs for them?

Comment: As with anything in Linux: it is YOUR choice. It really depends on what you want to do :)

Comment: A programming language is a means to an end. First you have to know what you're going to program. That the answer might change based on whether you want to write a web service or a device driver. "What is a good language to develop `$SOMETHING_SPECIFIC` on Ubuntu. " is a better question.

Comment: But I had wanted to add that a question like this does make sense for certain platforms. Some platforms are built around a toolchain which makes some language preferred for that platform. E.g. apps in some browser-based system might best be written in Javascript, HTML and CSS. Or Android apps in Java. But Ubuntu is a rich operating system where many ideas converge from different corners of computing.

Answer (score 4):

@ShockWave: I would say python, via quickly http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/tools/quickly/. Ubuntu provides some pretty neat tools to get you started. c++, via qtCreator, is also a good choice.

Comment: From the comments here it seems like python is a good choice so I'll look into that. PS. I have QT Creator but how do i get an executable from it. As in, how will launch the app without using Terminal?

Comment: @ShockWave You should probably post your QT-Creator question on a separate question, it would be easier to find. I don't have much experience with the IDE myself, and am unsure how to answer.

Comment: @ShockWave Linux folks tend to like Python and from what little I have seen there is a good reason for that. However, I used to program a lot and I loved C# and GTK# for Linux development. You should consider it.

Comment: +1 for Py, it's the simplest, fastest (in terms of dev time) and damn near everything in a modern Lunix distro has a Py API.

Answer (score 2):

I have worked with Java and Eclipse (and NetBeans) in Ubuntu quite extensively.  The nice thing about Java, is that it is portable to any platform that can run a JVM (for example: Minecraft runs on Linux, Windows, OSX, XBOX, etc...).

If you like C#, you should really check-out [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page).  It is an open source implementation of the .Net framework that will allow you to build C# apps with the [MonoDevelop IDE](http://monodevelop.com/).

Edit:

> I have to run it from inside the IDE. How do I get a stand alone app?

If you're having trouble getting compiled apps to run, check out this tutorial video: [youtube.com/watch?v=KW4G7R6zARs](http://youtube.com/watch?v=KW4G7R6zARs) It goes over how to do a quick "hello world" app in Mono on Ubuntu. At 3:10, the author shows how to create a launcher to his compiled Mono app.  If you follow his directory paths, you should be able to see where your compiled apps are ending-up.

Comment: I do love Mono-develop and have it, However I have to run it from inside the IDE. How do I get a stand alone app?

Comment: @ShockWave edit made.

Answer (score 1):

C# programming with via Mono and MonoDevelop, using GTK# for the GUI is excellent. I think you'll find the switch-over from Visual Studio quite simple after a little getting used to. I find that I prefer GTK# to WPF.

Answer (score 1):

If you already know C++ then you must already be programming at a lower level and have a better understanding of how to get the most out of the language.  GCC provides a more complete implementation of C++ x11 then most other platforms so I would stick with that; using Eclipse and the C++ plugin.  I would also pick up Python and QML since it shouldn't be too hard for you and they would be useful to know.  Python in Eclipse using pydev is a good system to use and you would have a single tool that provides both languages.

Answer (score 0):

I think ubuntu supports wide variety of languages even [C#](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page). If you are thinking about building ubuntu apps and like GNOME, I would say [vala](https://live.gnome.org/Vala). You can do this in C as well as C++ and also many other languages but I have heard Vala is similar to C# and much more high level than C or C++. If you need cross platform go for C++ with QT framework or Java. Since python is installed by default and is a very good multipurpose language with many modules, you can go for python as well.

By the way, nowadays ubuntu is embracing QT a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Python? You could use the `gedit` text editor. Search 'gedit' in the dash.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think the OP is asking *what* language is the best to use..  Not what tools to use.

Comment: @Seth - I have said - Python.